# SQL Query select from many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 5 Tables like this:

- **TABLE 1:** PRIMARY_KEY,NAME,FK_TABLE2
- **TABLE 2:** PRIMARY_KEY,FK_TABLE3
- **TABLE 3:** PRIMARY_KEY,FK_TABLE4
- **TABLE 4:** PRIMARY_KEY,FK_TABLE5
- **TABLE 5:** PRIMARY_KEY,DIAGRAM_NAME

And what I want is when I search for a name in a search bar, it returns `Name` from `Table1`, and also `DIAGRAM_NAME` from `table 5`.
The first part is easy:

```
SELECT `TABLE1`.name 
from Table 1 
Where `TABLE1`.name LIKE '%$search%'
```

But for the second part I need your help...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT T.Name, T5.Diagram_Name
FROM Table1 T
   JOIN Table2 T2 ON T.FK_TABLE2 = T2.PRIMARY_KEY
   JOIN Table3 T3 ON T2.FK_TABLE3 = T3.PRIMARY_KEY
   JOIN Table4 T4 ON T3.FK_TABLE4 = T4.PRIMARY_KEY
   JOIN Table5 T5 ON T4.FK_TABLE5 = T5.PRIMARY_KEY
WHERE T.Name LIKE '%$search%'
```

If you want to return the names that don't have matching diagram names, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Good luck.

Comment: you probably meant `T5.Diagram_Name`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to `JOIN` the tables using the `Primary Key` and `FK` values:

```
select t1.name, t5.DIAGRAM_NAME
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.FK_TABLE2 = t2.PRIMARY_KEY
left join table3 t3
    on t2.FK_TABLE2 = t3.PRIMARY_KEY
left join table4 t4
    on t3.FK_TABLE3 = t4.PRIMARY_KEY
left join table5 t5
    on t4.FK_TABLE4 = t5.PRIMARY_KEY    
Where t1.name LIKE '%$search%'
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

I used a `LEFT JOIN` in my example query, which will return all rows from `table1` even if there is not a matching row in the remaining tables.

If you know that there is a matching row in all of the tables that you are joining, then you can use an `INNER JOIN`.